# Swift parse query results not appearing in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I am running into difficulty displaying the data from the query I made in the individual cells of my tableview. I believe that my logic is correct, but I'm not seeing the console.log's that I am calling within my function that contains the Parse queried data. This might be a simple fix, but it isn't coming to me at the moment. The console log I should be seeing to validate that my query is coming through correctly is the `println("\(objects.count) users are listed")`, it should then be displayed within the `usernameLabel.text` property.

```
import UIKit

class SearchUsersRegistrationViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var userArray : NSMutableArray = []

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        loadParseData()

    }

    func loadParseData() {
        var query : PFQuery = PFUser.query()

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                if let objects = objects { 
                    println("\(objects.count) users are listed")
                    for object in objects {
                        self.userArray.addObject(object)
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } else {
                println("There is an error")
            }
        }
    }

    let textCellIdentifier = "Cell"

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.userArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SearchUsersRegistrationTableViewCell
        let row = indexPath.row
        let cellDataParse : PFObject = self.userArray.objectAtIndex(row) as! PFObject

        //cell.userImage.image = UIImage(named: usersArr[row])
        cell.usernameLabel.text = cellDataParse.objectForKey("_User") as! String

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Is loadParseData() being called?

Comment: sorry, I updated my question to make the call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue. I needed to cast the index path row in the users array as a `PFUser` and then cast the user's username property as a String and then set that as the label text.

```
        let row = indexPath.row

        var user = userArray[row] as! PFUser
        var username = user.username as String

        cell.usernameLabel.text = username
```