# Swift reloadTableView after queryForTable

Tags: swift, uitableview, pfquery

I have a tableView and a segmentControlView which does a different query from the database but I can't get the table to reload. If I manually reload the data changes.

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
        var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className:"movies")

    if(objects?.count == 0)
    {
        query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheThenNetwork
    }
     if self.currentSegmentSelected == 0 {
        query.whereKey("genres", equalTo:"Action")
        query.orderByAscending("title")
     }
    else if currentSegmentSelected == 1 {
        query.whereKey("genres", equalTo:"Comedy")
        query.orderByAscending("title")
     }
    else if currentSegmentSelected == 2 {
        query.whereKey("genres", equalTo:"Crime")
        query.orderByAscending("title")
     }
    return query
}
```

And the delegate method of the SegmentControl

```
func segmentView(segmentView: SMSegmentView, didSelectSegmentAtIndex index: Int) {
        self.currentSegmentSelected = index
        queryForTable()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

EDITED :
If I used .findObjectsInThebackground like this :

```
 override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
        var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className:"movies")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (_: [PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
             if error == nil {

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }}
```

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.'

Comment: couldnt get what you want. Do you want the table to reload after what?

Comment: after the segment is selected I want the table to reload. but I think the table reloads before the queryForTable is finished

Comment: executing a `PFQuery` works asynchronously. Update the table in the block  after returning the data

Comment: self.tableView.reloadData() inside queryForTable() ? should I use the main_queue ?

Comment: Where do you call `findObjectsInBackground…` ?

Comment: I return the query as shown and I use it in my tableView , I dont have the object localy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough to just make your query, you'll have to call it somewhere:

```
func segmentView(segmentView: SMSegmentView, didSelectSegmentAtIndex index: Int) {
    self.currentSegmentSelected = index
    queryForTable().findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { [weak self] objects, error in
        if error == nil {
            // Do whatever with `objects` and set it to your data source, whatever you named it.
            self?.yourDataSourceArray = objects
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Value of type PFQuery has no member findObjectsInBackgroundWithCompletion

Comment: Sorry about that, memory must be a bit fuzzy.  It's `backgroundWithBlock` see my updates @PoolHallJunkie

Comment: you are correct , it turns out queryForTable is not async so the findObjects inside was not ok. However not even now the table is reloading ... I am accessing the PFObject from cellForRowAtIndexPath. I don't have the data stored locally.

Comment: When dealing with PFTableViewController use only  self?.loadObjects() . Please update your answer

Comment: I didn't realize this was a `PFQueryTableViewController`.  What if you keep everything the way it was and call `self?.loadObjects` instead of `self?.tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: that was the problem yes , although my queries were also not that optimal.

Answer (score 0):

For jobs like this you should use `query.findObjectsInBackground`. It will problably demand some refactoring in your code but will turn your app much more responsive and user friendly.

Take a look at this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6kTw_cK3zY). It might help.

The code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29834791/swift-parse-query-results-not-appearing-in-tableview) should be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was wrong for two reasons.
First the `queryForTable()` is not async so as Logan pointed out . `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` must be outside.

But , `PFQueryTableViewController` is a Parse Class where `self.tableView.reloadData()` is not working.

instead , the fix :

```
self?.loadObjects
```